# searching a model in rails for 2 values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote this retrieval statement to check if an appointment being saved or created dosent conflict with one thats already saved. but its not working, can someone please point me to where I'm going wrong?

```
@new_appointment = :appointment #which is the params of appointment being sent back from submit.
@appointments = Appointment.all(:conditions => { :date_of_appointment => @new_appointment.date_of_appointment, :trainer_id => @new_appointment.trainer_id}
```

)

the error is from the `:date_of_appointment => @new_appointment.date_of_appointment` this will always be false as:

thank you

Comment: How does your `Appointment` model looks like? Can you please post that here.

Comment: question updated. new problem come up. i didnt know if i was meant to create a new question or just update this one.

Comment: This really should have been a separate question because the question is completely different.

Comment: im sorry, should i return the question to the way it was and create a new question?

Comment: I would rollback your edit and create a new question.

Comment: done. i posted the new question if you can please have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At face value, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your syntax. My guess is that `@new_appointment` isn't containing the values you're expecting, and thus the database query is returning different values than you expect.

Try dumping out `@new_appointment.inspect` or check the logfiles to see what SQL the finder is producing, or use

```
Appointment.send(:construct_finder_sql, :conditions => {
  :date_of_appointment => @new_appointment.date_of_appointment,
  :trainer_id => @new_appointment.trainer_id
})
```

to see the SQL that will be generated (`construct_finder_sql` is a protected `ActiveRecord::Base` method).

---

**Update based on your edit**

`@new_appointment = :appointment` should be something like `@new_appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])`. `:appointment` is just a symbol, it is not automatically related to your params unless you tell it to.

Comment: hi i updated the question, yes you are right, for some reason it has date_of_appointment with 3 different values, "date_of_appointment(2i)"=>"3",
"date_of_appointment(3i)"=>"10",
"date_of_appointment(1i)"=>"2012"

how can i make the check? thanks

Comment: They come from date_select helper and can be converted as so: 

http://gist.github.com/331737

Comment: the method still dosent work because it can not retrieve the appointments that match the conditions specified. appointments is always empty.

Comment: problem is with trying to compare dates. rails handles this very weird:
'irb(main):014:0> dn == d
=> false
irb(main):015:0> dn.to_s
=> "2012-07-03"
irb(main):016:0> d.to_s
=> "2010-07-03"
irb(main):017:0> '

two dates are the same yet if you compare they are false. any way around this?

Comment: i changed it to '@new_appointment = person.appointments.build(params[:appointment])' and it works great for the update method (identifies conflicts) but dosent work for create method. very odd. this is driving me mad, i will give you the right answer but if you know why its doing that it would be great. thanks